# IE7 Drag and Drop links to TextArea

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

Why in IE7 does it prohibit me from dragging URL's/images links...etc into a TextArea?

**This does not work:**

In IE go to Tools > Internet Options > Security

Select Internet from the list of Zones and click the Custom level... button.

Scroll down to the Miscellaneous section and look for Drag and drop or copy and paste files.

Make sure Enable is selected.

Click OK, Apply, OK.

*NOTE:  I can drag to tabs.

RESOURCE URL FOR ACCEPTED ANSWER:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533743%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following JavaScript code into you page enables dragging links to textarea in IE.

```
/* FIX IE of not allowing dropping links into textarea. */
document.ondragstart = function () {
    window.event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copyLink";
};
```